# How to show that SABR is log-normal for $\beta=1$ and normal for $\beta=0$?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-volatility, sabr

For $\beta = 1$ SABR is log-normally distributed and for for $\beta = 0$ SABR is normally distributed. This is a very common property mentioned in almost every paper about SABR. But I can't find the mathematical derivation (It might be really  simple to derive), which leads to my question:

**How I proof that SABR is log-normal for $\beta=1$ and normal for $\beta=0$?**

Comment: I don't think it's true that the underlying distribution is perfectly lognormal/normal in those cases.  The presence of stochastic vol will give the distribution fat tails, for example.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this statement?

Comment: Hagan's paper Managing Smile Risk has a chart of the smile for Beta=0 and 1 (if the implied vol has a smile then the distribution must be fat tailed)

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost it is important to clarify that the underlying is not necessarily normal/lognormal but for the special cases of $\beta$ the underlying is normal/lognormal *Conditioned on a realization of the volatility*. As mentioned in the answer by @ilovevolatility. Simple stochastic calculus will show the properties you mentioned. 
For *realized volatility* the following holds: 
$$
dS_t = S_t^\beta\sigma_tdW_t, 
$$
For $\beta=1$, $dS_t=S_t\sigma_tdW_t$, $S_t$ becomes a ***geometric brownian motion*** which means that at time $t$ the distribution of $\log S_t$ is given:
$$
\log S_T \sim N(S_t,\sigma_t^2(T-t))
$$
For $\beta=0$:
$$dS_t=\sigma_tdW_t$$
which can be written in integral form
$$
S_T=S_t + \int^T_t \sigma_t^2 dW_u
$$
According to stochastic calculus theory the integral is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\sigma_t^2(T-t)$:
$$ S_T \sim N(S_t,\sigma_t^2(T-t))$$

Answer (score 1):

Given (conditional on) a realisation of the volatility, it is normal for $\beta = 0$ and lognormal for $\beta = 1$

Answer (score 0):

The longer term process is not (unless alpha=0).